# How to make a function that returns all integers that are multiples of either parameters n1 or n2 within the list n

Tags: python

The 3 parameters: list of integers (n), integer number (n1), and another integer number (n2), not including 0

I have:

```
def hw(n, n1, n2):
    multiples = []
    for i in n:
        if i % n1 == 0 and i % n2 == 0:
            return multiples
```

which is wrong and not even returning anything. I'm not sure where I went wrong, though?
the test script:

```
sol= hw(np.arange(20), 3, 4)
assert sol==[3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16, 18]
```

Comment: please revise your question

Comment: your assert also seem to have problem: `[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]` is not the right list to match against for the description for multiples of `3` and `4`, it should be just `[0, 12]` as `3`, `6`, `9`, `15` and  `18` are not multiples of 4.

Comment: sorry, it was multiples of 3 or 4

Comment: even with 3 or 4, there will be more items like `4`, `8`, `16`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `return` you just return from the function in the very first iteration, you need to `append` to the list and return the list outside of the loop.

```
def hw(n, n1, n2):
    multiples = []
    for i in n:
        if i % n1 == 0 or i % n2 == 0:
            multiples.append(i)
    return multiples
```

Also, use `or` instead of `and` if you need multiples of `3` or `4`.

Comment: btw, you can do all of this in one line with list comprehension with: `return [i for i in n if i%n1 == 0  and i%n2 == 0]`

Comment: it gives assertionError because this output does not match

Comment: can you please give an example, it could be problem with the logic itself?

Comment: the question was not clear and need to be clearly explained.

Comment: yes, I just noticed the assert, there is definitely some logic problem since the assert list is not in line with the description of the question

Comment: aaaa sorry, there is a problem with my logic. I'm trying to figure it out to edit the post

Comment: use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66487237/edit) link to edit the post, @kwispychickyjoy

Comment: thank you, i think what i've made returns a list of numbers divisible by 2 that are in n

Comment: `[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]` this list just represents the elements divisible by `3` (excluding `0`).

Comment: oh i just noticed now. this question was from a school problem set so im not sure why it's like that...

Comment: anyway, I have updated the answer to mention to use `or` instead of `and` if you need multiples of `n1` or `n2`.

Comment: i've also updated the post, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it using list comprehension:

```
def fun(n, n1, n2):
    multiples = [i for i in n if i % n1 == 0 and i % n2 == 0]
    return multiples

res = fun([18, 23, 21, 42, 3], 3, 7)
print(res)
```